# Drag the weblink of a file to a dired folder to save in that folder

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows, directories

Assume that I am visiting a folder (directory) on my system by `M-x dired` in Emacs. Also assume that I am visiting a webpage like http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/pdf/ by the default web browser of my system (say Mozilla Firefox). If I drag the link `elisp.pdf` from this webpage and drop it on that dired buffer, the most natural things that one wishes to happen is to save the file `elisp.pdf` in that folder.

What are the most natural way to achieve this in Emacs?

Comment: Have a look at [`org-download`](https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download) (visual demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAojpHR-6Uo)), it provides functionality that is very similar to what you describe.

Comment: @itsjeyd org-download is for moving images. For images, drag and drop to a dired works without any external package (no need to org-download). So my question remains.

Comment: @itsjeyd, you're ahead of me:). I just pushed a `dired`-specific feature a minute ago.

Answer (score 1):

I just added this feature to [org-download](https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download).

Here's the implementation:

```
(defun org-download-dired (uri)
  "Download URI to current directory."
  (raise-frame)
  (let ((filename (file-name-nondirectory
                   (car (url-path-and-query
                         (url-generic-parse-url uri))))))
    (message "Downloading %s to %s ..."
             filename
             (expand-file-name filename))
    (url-retrieve
     uri
     (lambda (status filename)
       (let ((err (plist-get status :error)))
         (if err (error
                  "\"%s\" %s" uri
                  (downcase (nth 2 (assq (nth 2 err) url-http-codes))))))
       (let ((coding-system-for-write 'no-conversion))
         (write-region nil nil filename nil nil nil 'confirm)))
     (list
      (expand-file-name filename))
     t t)))
```

You just need to appropriately tie in the above function with `dnd-protocol-alist`.
But a plain `(require 'org-download)` should suffice.

Comment: That's weird. Can you `edebug` `org-download-dired`?

Comment: I downloaded `org-download.el` and I put `(require 'org-download)` but Emacs doesn't react in draging the link. I also put the above code in .emacs but still unsuccessful. Maybe I miss something here.

Comment: Can you eval `dnd-protocol-alist`?

Comment: Yes it gives `(("^file:///" . dired-dnd-handle-local-file) ("^file://" . dired-dnd-handle-file) ("^file:" . dired-dnd-handle-local-file) ("^\\(https?\\|ftp\\|file\\|nfs\\)://" . org-download-dnd) ("^file:///" . dnd-open-local-file) ("^file://" . dnd-open-file) ("^file:" . dnd-open-local-file) ("^\\(https?\\|ftp\\|file\\|nfs\\)://" . dnd-open-file))`.

Comment: OK, it looks like `org-download-dnd` should be called. Is it called? What's your operating system?

Comment: I am on Windows 7. How I can call `org-download-dnd`? `M-x org-download-dnd` seems to not working.

Comment: Sorry, currently `org-download-dnd` is known not to work on Windows (works on Linux and OSX). Maybe someone with Windows experience can explain why `dnd-protocol-alist` doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: There was an issue before where it wasn't working for 24.3.1 on OSX, but was working for 24.4.1.

Comment: I use Emacs 24.4.1.

Comment: abo-abo in your code which command actually download the file? I ask this question because I have Wget on my system, and probably it would be possible that your code can be modified to work, But I am not sure.

Comment: By the way I have a question about the source of org-download.el. In the last lines of this file there is `(https?\\ ` I am wondering if it should be `(http?\\ ` instead. But probably I am wrong.

Comment: Try to eval `(org-download-dired "http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/pdf/elisp.pdf")` while in a some dired buffer. That's all there is to it. `dnd-protocol-alist` will just call this function when you drag-and-drop.

Comment: https? means either `http` or `https`. s? means zero or one s.